# query to get customer list using JOIN with sum () of the amounts spent in orders

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sum

I have the following tables

table **anag** (customer registry)

---

```
  id  |  surname   |  name  |     phone      | 
----------------------------------------------
  1   |  Brown     |  Jack  |  +3989265781   |
  2   |  Smith     |  Bill  |  +3954872358   |
  3   |  Rogers    |  Stan  |  +3912568453   |
  4   |  Pickford  |  Eric  |  +3948521358   |
----------------------------------------------
```

table **levels** (table that connects each customer to his salesperson. For database registration reasons, the link between customer and seller is given by the customer's telephone number)

---

```
  id  |  client_phone  |  id_seller  |
--------------------------------------
  1   |  +3989265781   |     4       | 
  2   |  +3954872358   |     7       |
  3   |  +3912568453   |     7       |
  4   |  +3948521358   |     8       |
--------------------------------------
```

table **orders** (contains all purchases made by customers, of course)

---

```
  id  |  id_client  |  id_item  |  id_seller  |  price  |  status  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
  1   |      1      |     2     |      4      |  12.50  |    2     |
  2   |      2      |     2     |      7      |  12.50  |    2     |
  3   |      2      |     3     |      7      |  10.00  |    3     |
  4   |      2      |     3     |      7      |  10.00  |    3     |
  5   |      2      |     4     |      7      |  20.50  |    1     |
  6   |      3      |     2     |      7      |  12.50  |    1     |
  7   |      3      |     5     |      7      |  19.00  |    3     |
  8   |      3      |     7     |      7      |  31.00  |    2     |
  9   |      4      |     1     |      8      |   5.00  |    1     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What I'm trying to do is get from the JOIN of these tables a complete list by seller of his customers sorted in descending order by the amount spent on orders as long as the order status is 2 or 3

Something like this (example seller id 7):

---

```
  id  |  surname  |  name  |  amaount  | 
----------------------------------------
  3   |  Rogers   |  Stan  |  50.00    |
  2   |  Smith    |  Bill  |  32.50    |
----------------------------------------
```

I have tried with this query which seems correct to me, but unfortunately it returns me error in fetch_assoc()

```
SELECT a.id, a.surname, a.name, o.amount FROM levels AS l
JOIN anag AS a ON a.phone = l.client_phone
JOIN {
    SELECT id_client, SUM(price) AS amount FROM orders
    WHERE id_seller = '7' AND (status = '2' OR status = '3') GROUP BY id_client
} AS o ON o.id_client = a.id
WHERE l.id_seller = '7'
ORDER BY o.amount DESC
```

If I separate the subquery from the main query, both return the data I expect and it seems strange to me the JOIN between the two does not work properly

Comment: FYI [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only real error is using curly braces instead of parentheses:

```
SELECT a.id, a.surname, a.name, o.amount
FROM levels l JOIN
     anag a
     ON a.phone = l.client_phone JOIN
     (SELECT id_client, SUM(price) AS amount
      FROM orders
      WHERE id_seller = '7' AND status IN ('2', '3'))
      GROUP BY id_client
     ) o
     ON o.id_client = a.id
WHERE l.id_seller = '7'
ORDER BY o.amount DESC;
```

In addition:

- You can use `IN` to shorten an equality comparison to multiple values.
- Although I left them in, `status` and `id_seller` look like numbers.  If so, drop the single quotes.  Don't mix data types.
- Your question is ambiguous on what to do if the seller in `orders` differs from the seller in `anag` for a customer.  This keeps your logic (the sellers need to match).

Comment: Did I make such a trivial mistake? So it seems. Thanks, I just couldn't get it. I'll try your suggestion with IN. The status and id_seller parameters are obtained from some variables, I wanted to avoid having to rework in the future if the data were changed to strings. Once registered, a user is forever linked to that seller, so logically he will never be able to ask himself this problem

Answer (score 0):

SELECT a.id, a.surname, a.name,  sum(o.price)   'amount'

FROM  anag a

LEFT JOIN levels l ON  l.id =a.id

LEFT  JOIN orders of ON o.id_seller = l.id_seller AND o.id_client = l.id

GROUP  BY o.id_seller

ORDER  BY amount DESC